# Generic types in an array for a tree with more than one child

Tags: java, arrays, generics, types, tree

I am trying to implement a tree with more than one child and I need to store these children somehow. I decided I could use a `LinkedList` but I want to try and use an array first.

(Please I do not want to use any Imports.)

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
{
    Node<T> arrChildren[] = new Node<T>[size];
}
```

This does not work.

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
{
    Comparable<Node<T>> arrChildren[] = new Comparable[size];
    T element;
}
```

This works but I cannot compare the `arrChildren[0]` with a normal `Node<T>` and if I make all my `Node<T>`s `Comparable` Nodes I cannot reach the elements inside.

This is my first post on Stack overflow I hope too get a good response, I dont mind criticism.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics and arrays simply do not mix well in Java. It will be much easier to just use a `List<T>` implementation like you were considering:

```
List<Node<T>> arrChildren = new LinkedList<>();
```

**Longer explanation:**

Arrays:

- Keep track of their component type at runtime.
- Are covariant (an `Integer[]` is a `Number[]` is an `Object[]`).

Generic types:

- Have their type arguments [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) by the compiler such that they aren't available at runtime. Calls to a `Node<String>` become calls to a `Node` with appropriate casts to `String`.
- Aren't covariant (a `List<Integer>` is *not* a `List<Number>`).

The reason `new Node<T>[size]` isn't allowed is because the array needs to know its component type at runtime, at which point there's no longer a concept of `T`. Only something like `new Node<?>[size]` is permissible.

Ignoring the restriction on creating an array of `Node<T>`, simply having a reference to one isn't safe because the following scenario is possible:

```
Node<Integer>[] intNodeArray = ...;
Object[] objArray = intNodeArray; //legal because arrays are covariant
objArray[0] = new Node<String>("asfd"); //should fail but doesn't

...

//sometime later
Node<Integer> intNode = intNodeArray[0]; //still doesn't fail because of erasure
Integer i = intNode.getValue(); //only now do we get a runtime exception
```

Adding a `Node<String>` to the array *should* throw a runtime exception, but it doesn't because the array only knows that its component type is `Node`, not `Node<Integer>`.

For more information, see Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ: [Can I create an array whose component type is a concrete parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type?)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I ended up using this "Node<T> [] arrChildren = new Node[size];" combined with the comparable in the class declaration and it actually worked perfectly. I could access arrChildren[0].elements;. Is it just bad practice? I think mine worked because in this case I actually wanted a reference to the Nodes and programmed my Tree in such a way that I would never lose contact with the memory referenced. Does this make sense? I didn't want to use List from the start because if I wanted to use a Linked List I would have had to make it myself.

Comment: @Enfodo That should be fine as long as you hide it as an implementation detail and stay cognizant of the scenario I demonstrated - I didn't realize that you literally couldn't import anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node<T>[] arrChildren = (Node<T>[])new Node<?>[size];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I ended up using this. except I excluded the (Node<T>[]). From what I gather it is a conversion I would use it to make a float a integer, but what does it do in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @Enfodo You're using `new Node[size]`, where plain `Node` is a raw type. It's implicitly doing the same thing as this answer.