# Why there is no ArrayStoreException thrown in below code?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
private static void genericArrayTest() {
    ArrayList<? extends Exception>[] exceptionListArray = new ArrayList[10]; 
    Object[] exceptionObjectListArray  = exceptionListArray;

    ArrayList<String> wrongArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    wrongArrayList.add("String One");

    ArrayList<NullPointerException> exceptionList = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList rawList = new ArrayList();

    exceptionListArray[0] = exceptionList;
    //exceptionListArray[0] = wrongArrayList; // Compile error?
    //exceptionListArray[0] = rawList;

    exceptionObjectListArray[0] = wrongArrayList; 
// No compile time error, there is no ArrayStoreException why ?

    ArrayList<? extends Exception> list = exceptionListArray[0]; // No exception here as well ??
    Exception e = list.get(0); 
// Exception only when accessing data, why not ArrayStoreException when we stored wrong list ??
    System.out.println();
}
```

Can someone please explain what is going on ?

Google search says below array declaration is allowed 
 `ArrayList<Exception>[] exceptionListArray = new ArrayList[10];`

 but not this 
`ArrayList<Exception>[] exceptionListArray = new ArrayList<Exception>[10];`

What is the difference between these two declaration & why one is allowed not other one?

[Creating an array to store generic types in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415255/creating-an-array-to-store-generic-types-in-java) is talks about how to create generic array. But this question is not about how to create generic array, its about why ArrayStoreException is not thrown at runtime & difference in generic array creation syntax in java

Comment: Check here for your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16415586/986169. Regarding exceptionObjectListArray, it is declared as an array of Object types. So any array of a type that extends Object can be assigned to it.

Comment: @giorashc From above link, I got into - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays. It says "If arrays of parameterized lists were allowed, code would fail to throw the desired ArrayStoreException". But, it is happening now as well with above code block correct ? So the question is what does java achieved by allowing 'ArrayList<Exception>[] exceptionListArray = new ArrayList[10]; ' ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an array to store generic types in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415255/creating-an-array-to-store-generic-types-in-java)

Comment: I don't think that's a complete duplicate because this question asks about ArrayStoreException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, generic parameterizations do not have a class which distinguishes them from each other:

```
ArrayList<Exception> : class is ArrayList
ArrayList<String>    : class is ArrayList
```

This is because generics are implemented with [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which means that during compilation, they are replaced with casting:

```
ArrayList<Exception> list = new ArrayList<Exception>();
list.add(new Exception());
Exception e = list.get(0);
```

becomes:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new Exception());
Exception e = (Exception) list.get(0);
```

No `ArrayStoreException` is thrown because `ArrayList<Exception>` and `ArrayList<String>` have the same type during program execution.

A generic array is disallowed because there is no way to perform these checks on the type parameters during execution. (Because the type parameters don't exist anymore.)

When we have this:

```
ArrayList<Exception>[] a =
    new ArrayList[10];
```

It's called an unchecked conversion. `a` is actually an `ArrayList[]`, an array which stores any `ArrayList` but we've basically said *"pretend it's an `ArrayList<Exception>[]` for the time being"*. The array object `a` points to is still an `ArrayList[]`.

---

See the following program to illustrate:

```
import java.util.*;

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Exception> a = new ArrayList<Exception>();
        ArrayList<String>    b = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("ArrayList<Exception> class is:");
        System.out.println("\t" + a.getClass());
        System.out.println("ArrayList<String> class is:");
        System.out.println("\t" + b.getClass());
        System.out.println(
            "ArrayList<Exception> class == ArrayList<String> class:");
        System.out.println("\t" + ( a.getClass() == b.getClass() ));

        ArrayList<Exception>[] c = new ArrayList[0];
        ArrayList<String>[]    d = new ArrayList[0];

        System.out.println("ArrayList<Exception>[] class is:");
        System.out.println("\t" + c.getClass());
        System.out.println("ArrayList<String>[] class is:");
        System.out.println("\t" + d.getClass());
        System.out.println(
            "ArrayList<Exception>[] class == ArrayList<String>[] class:");
        System.out.println("\t" + ( c.getClass() == d.getClass() ));
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/dfCZjy

Output:

```
ArrayList<Exception> class is:
    class java.util.ArrayList
ArrayList<String> class is:
    class java.util.ArrayList
ArrayList<Exception> class == ArrayList<String> class:
    true
ArrayList<Exception>[] class is:
    class [Ljava.util.ArrayList;
ArrayList<String>[] class is:
    class [Ljava.util.ArrayList;
ArrayList<Exception>[] class == ArrayList<String>[] class:
    true
```

Comment: Type erasure or not, every class in Java extends from `Object`. I guess that should be sufficient to explain why an `ArrayStoreException` is not thrown.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I don't really see how that's relevant.

Comment: @ChetanKinger That's not relevant because the class of `exceptionObjectListArray` is `ArrayList[]`, not `Object[]`. It is possible to get an `ArrayStoreException` for an array with compile-time type `Object[]`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Can you elaborate on what you mean by `the class of exceptionObjectListArray is ArrayList[]`? Do you mean at runtime because at compile time, it is an `Object[]` array right?

Comment: @ChetanKinger Try [`exceptionObjectListArray.getClass()`](http://ideone.com/ThCL25)

Comment: @ChetanKinger Yes, at runtime. If you use `a = new ArrayList[]`, `a.getClass()` will show you it's an `ArrayList[]`. You get the same result if you write `Object[] b = a` and then do `b.getClass()`. Even though the compile-time type of `b` is `Object[]` it will still throw an `ArrayStoreException` at runtime if you put something in it that is not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Understood. @Radiodef, `exceptionObjectListArray.getClass()` is the runtime type. Thus the quesiton.

Comment: @Radiodef Thanks for the explanation. I have one small clarification. Though `a` is `ArrayList[]`, compiler complains if we do `a[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>()`. Why compiler is designed such a way, when it's not going to matter anyway during runtime ? Compiler can accept that statement right as runtime is not going to have any issues with that statement ?

Comment: @Radiodef In your terms why compiler is pretending to be `ArrayList<Exception>[]` when it does not matter at all during runtime ? Both compiler & runtime should think in same way isn't it ?

Comment: @Radiodef It's not `a` it's `c` & `c[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>()` Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Generics are preventing us from making a certain kind of error which arrays allow us to do. The generic type system altogether disallows the situation which causes an `ArrayStoreException`. What you have here is a strange collision between different systems which were [designed with different motivations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18666710/2891664). The sound advice is to not try to use both. Instead pick one or the other, either `Exception[][]` or `List<List<Exception>>`. There isn't a good reason they behave this way when they are combined.